# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to write SOAP Message

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, weblogic12c

Trying to make a Soap call from weblogic and using the following code. But the below error is showing up, I am not sure if the response is coming from the webservice. Please help. Error is pointing to the line number with "System.out.println("Response body" +  sMsg.getSOAPBody());" in the below code.

```
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = 
        SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = 
                                   soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();            
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage message = messageFactory.createMessage(new 
        MimeHeaders(), new 
          ByteArrayInputStream(request.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));

        message.getMimeHeaders().addHeader("SOAPAction",soapAction);
        SOAPMessage sMsg = soapConnection.call(message, Url);

        System.out.println("Response body" +  sMsg.getSOAPBody());
        ByteArrayOutputStream soapResponseStream = new 
                                                    ByteArrayOutputStream();
        sMsg.writeTo(soapResponseStream);   
        output = soapResponseStream.toString("UTF-8");

        soapConnection.close();
```

**Below Error is showing up:**

```
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to write SOAP Message
                   at 
oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.util.XMLWriter.internalWriteElement(XMLWriter.java:173) 
[com.oracle.webservices.orasaaj-rt-api_12.1.3.jar:]
at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.util.XMLWriter.writeElement(XMLWriter.java:61) 
[com.oracle.webservices.orasaaj-rt-api_12.1.3.jar:]
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.util.XMLWriter.writeElement(XMLWriter.java:478)[com.oracle.webservices.orasaaj-rt-api_12.1.3.jar:]
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.ElementImpl.toString(ElementImpl.java:1162)[com.oracle.webservices.orasaaj-rt-api_12.1.3.jar:]
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2849)[:1.7.0_121]
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)[:1.7.0_121]
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem got resolved. Basically the issue was the response. The response has improper characters (tags) in it which were causing this issue.